# Can I make a custom JIRA Cloud plug-in that my whole team can use?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am looking into making a custom plugin to generate some custom reports for JIRA Cloud. I know I can make a custom plugin on my computer, but will it only be available to me? Or will other members of my team be able to use the plugin on their computers as well?

Answer (score 1):

Please read how cloud app in general works.
Please read this document thoroughly after that: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/guides/introduction.html#architecture-graphic